# POST two form inputs with same name but different type

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I have a webpage that submits two inputs in a form. My browser's POST can be seen below.
The first input is the path to the current file uploaded to the site (`type="hidden"`); the second input is the new file to be uploaded (`type="file"`).

```
-----------------------------334620328614915644833547167693
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image1"

data/file.jpg
-----------------------------334620328614915644833547167693
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image1"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

These inputs have the same name but are typed differently, which causes problems with my understanding of the `requests` library. As far as I know, to submit data, you POST a dictionary with the name of the input and its new value.

```py
data = {}

form = get_all_forms(url)[1] #function returns list of forms gained using requests.get() - we select the correct form
formDetails = get_form_details(form) #uses BeautifulSoup to find all input values
for inputTag in formDetails["inputs"]:
  if inputTag["type"] == "file":
    pass #doesn't send anything
  else:
    data[inputTag["name"]] = inputTag["value"] #sets to current value

res = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

The above code will POST a dictionary with `'image1':'data/file.jpg'`. Unfortunately, the page now thinks that there is a new file being uploaded called `data/file.jpg`, and when it can't find that file, it deletes the current image.

How do I POST separate values for `type="file"` and `type="hidden"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, just a suggestion: consider using different, more significant `name` attributes for your form fields (emphasis on different!). In your case, something like this would make more sense:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="old-file-path" value="data/file.jpg"/>
<input type="file" name="new-file"/>
```

---

Now, coming to the actual question, you can achieve what you want using both the `data=` and `files=` parameters of `requests.post()`, like this:

```py
new_file = open('path/to/new/file.jpg', 'wb')
data     = {'image1': 'data/file.jpg'}
files    = {'image1': new_file}

requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)
```

Which should generate a request like this:

```
...
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=d64ebc3e14a4909699c6f01dd1473855

--d64ebc3e14a4909699c6f01dd1473855
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image1"

data/file.jpg
--d64ebc3e14a4909699c6f01dd1473855
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image1"; filename="file.jpg"
...
```

The key point here is to use `files=` for the new file to upload and `data=` for the old file name.

If you also want to explicitly set the new file's name and `Content-Type` you can pass a 3-items tuple in the `files=` dict instead, like this:

```py
new_file = open('path/to/new/file.jpg', 'wb')
data     = {'image1': 'data/file.jpg'}
files    = {'image1': ('NEW_FILE_NAME', new_file, 'application/octet-stream')}

requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)
```

Result:

```
...
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=d64ebc3e14a4909699c6f01dd1473855

--d64ebc3e14a4909699c6f01dd1473855
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image1"

data/file.jpg
--d64ebc3e14a4909699c6f01dd1473855
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image1"; filename="NEW_FILE_NAME"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
...
```

Or if you want to send a file from memory and not from disk, or even an empty file, you can use:

```py
from io import BytesIO
new_file = BytesIO(b'...file content here...')

# ... same code as above
```

---

Adapting this to your existing code, the whole thing should become:

```py
data = {}
files = {}
new_file = ... # obtain the new file somehow

for inputTag in formDetails["inputs"]:
    if inputTag["type"] == "file":
        files[inputTag["name"]] = ("NEW_FILE_NAME", new_file, "application/octect-stream")
    elif inputTag["type"] == "hidden":
        data[inputTag["name"]] = inputTag["value"]

requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)
```

---

Finally, in your bounty comment, I see you say:

> [...] and when I just need multiple values for the same input name.

In this case you would have to use a `list` instead of a dictionary for `data=`, like this:

```py
data = [('image1', 'A'), ('image1', 'B')]
# ...
requests.post(url, data=data)
```

And the result would look like this:

```
--9cc0d413be5d2ed2ba8c80a2e7b54442
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image1"

A
--9cc0d413be5d2ed2ba8c80a2e7b54442
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image1"

B
```

Whether or not this makes sense though is up to you to decide, as it depends on the server-side implementation and the meaning of the fields when using the same name multiple times.

Comment: `data` appears to override `files` when uploaded to the server. Might be this specific server's fault.

Comment: Certain it is ^; going to mark this as accepted.

Comment: Examining the documentation in fine detail I've noticed [this](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests), which supposedly allows you to submit multiple `value`s for one `name`; how would you identify the order for that?

Comment: @Corsaka thanks for the link, wasn't aware of that, it makes sense. I've updated my answer. Not sure what you mean by "how would you identify the order"; if you are referring to the order of the parts in the request body `requests` seems to respect the order of the `data=` list.